# Cassandra dont' listen on 7199 JMX port

Tags: cassandra

On one of my nodes I see in `netstat -ln` output:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.25.207:9160         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

On another for the same port:

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.25.208:9160  :::*                        LISTEN
```

And that's why I think on another node I can't see JMX 7199 port open. On first it's opened, I can see it with `netstat -ln | grep 7199` command:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

What's the difference in configuration of my system, why there is ipv6 on one node? Machines are equal, cassandra configs are equals too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, guys, my bad - I fell asleep on my keyboard while `vi` was opened on `/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh`, the file was corrupted.

Comment: You should accept your own answer: We have all been there, one way or another. :)